# how do I make contact information secure in a Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: security, xamarin.forms

I am making a Xamarin.Forms app for Android and iOS and I want to be able to create lists of contacts with a person's name, phone number, and email address. I want to make these list files secure, but I know basically nothing about security. What do I need to do?

Comment: If you want to encrypte this information, you can use this url https://github.com/851265601/ACommonUtils/blob/master/PassWordConvertUtils.cs to convert it, normally, we used above code to convert password to other string, then store converted string to DB.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I hope I don't sound ungrateful, but that reminds me of Xamarin's SecureStorage API, which isn't designed for large amounts of text. Why is this better?

Comment: Do you mean this Xamarin.Essentials: Secure Storage? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Yes I do.

Comment: Xamarin.Essentials: Secure Storage is designed for Key/Value data format, you need to secure the name, phone number and email address, it is not suitable for your needs, can use my provided code to custom secure, no matter what kind of strings, just you secure salt could parse it.